# Chart JS Logarithmic x-axis

Tags: chart.js

I want to create a graph with the x-axis logarithmic. I took an example and changed the type to logarithmic. But I am getting all y values on the y-axis itself(see attached).But when I make y-axis logarithmic, It is works as expected. I am using chartjs version 2.9.3. When I used 2.8.0 there was no output.

This is my code:

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <title>Logarithmic Line Chart</title>
        <script src="/PHP/test/Chart.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/PHP/test/utils.js"></script>
        <style>
            canvas {
                -moz-user-select: none;
                -webkit-user-select: none;
                -ms-user-select: none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div style="width:75%;">
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    </div>
    <button id="randomizeData">Randomize Data</button>
    <script>
        var randomScalingFactor = function() {
            return Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10.0) * Math.pow(10, Math.ceil(Math.random() * 5));
        };

        var config = {
            type: 'line',

            data: {
                labels: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15],
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'My First dataset',
                    backgroundColor: window.chartColors.red,
                    borderColor: window.chartColors.red,
                    fill: false,
                    data: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15],
                },]
            },
            options: {
                responsive: true,
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'Chart.js Line Chart - Logarithmic'
                },
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        stacked:false,
                        display: true,
                        type:'logarithmic',
                    }],
                    yAxes: [{
                        stacked:false,
                        display: true,

                    }]
                }
            }
        };

        window.onload = function() {
            var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas');
            window.myLine = new Chart(ctx, config);
        };

        document.getElementById('randomizeData').addEventListener('click', function() {
            config.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset) {
                dataset.data = dataset.data.map(function() {
                    return randomScalingFactor();
                });

            });

            window.myLine.update();
        });
    </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

[image: current incorrect output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both axes are numeric the data needs to be provided as an array of [points](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html?h=x%3A#point), i.e.:

```
[ { x: 111, y: 222 }, ... ]
```

From the documentation:

> This alternate is used for sparse datasets, such as those in [scatter charts](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/scatter.html#scatter-chart). Each data point is specified using an object containing `x` and `y` properties.

Here's a working example from the posted code:

```js
var config = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      label: 'My First dataset',
      backgroundColor: 'red',
      borderColor: 'red',
      fill: false,
      data: [
        { x: 1, y: 1 },
        { x: 2, y: 2 },
        { x: 3, y: 3 },
        { x: 4, y: 4 },
        { x: 5, y: 5 },
        { x: 6, y: 6 },
        { x: 7, y: 7 },
        { x: 8, y: 8 },
        { x: 9, y: 9 },
        { x: 10, y: 10 },
        { x: 11, y: 11 },
        { x: 12, y: 12 },
        { x: 13, y: 13 },
        { x: 14, y: 14 },
        { x: 15, y: 15 }
      ]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Chart.js Line Chart - Logarithmic'
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'logarithmic'
      }]
    }
  }
};

window.onload = function() {
  var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas');
  window.myLine = new Chart(ctx, config);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.3/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: And how to present this in a simple way?

Comment: I was talking about the JSON type of the data, used by logarithmic graphs in chart.js. More specifically, the ```{ x: 1, y: 0}, { x: 2, y: 1 }, ...``` way of writing this required too much effort of me to present it to the chart.js, since I am a non-professional programmer. However, I was able to do this with some struggling. This was not easy, because online they give so much info about how to add key, value pair to json, but not how to add key, value with the same key!!! Now I know this is in fact called adding an object to json! But it took me the whole day!